# How to decompile the way a hash was created? sha512managed

Tags: c#, asp.net, decompiler, sha512

i have a database table with a 88digits hash and a 16digits salt. i know the clear password because its my own testuser.

this user, password, hash and salt was created within a website / commercial tool.

I am trying to build my own .net website and would like to use the same user/password database table.

I tried different ways in .net and i found out that based on the length of the hash(88) is has to be a sha512 hashing.

i read the existing salt from the table and build a hash from password and salt. the outcome is different to the existing hash in the database table.

i believe my "sha512managed" is wrong or the commercial tool uses not only password + salt to create the hash. maybe the use Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(string.Concat("text" + password, salt)) or something.

i there any whay to figure this out?

Comment: While all software can be reverse engineered, you might violate the license agreement of that commercial tool if doing so. Such questions are inappropriate here.

Comment: What you want too do is reverse engineer not decompile. Decompile is when you have a compiled code and want to go back to the source code. Instead of looking at the data you better try to decompile the web application to see what operations it performs. Just looking at the data you can do endless tries and not find the correct algorithm.